# Python running MessageQueue.Peek via win32com, how to get timeout right?

Tags: python, msmq, win32com, pythoncom, msmq-wcf

For starters, I would like to say if anyone can help here, you are incredible.

**General Question**

My Python program needs to interact with MSMQ.  Basically, I want to peek at a queue, specifying a timeout if there's nothing in the queue.

However, despite my best efforts, I cannot get Peek() to wait out the timeout interval, when there's no value previously in the queue.  **Can you please point out what is missing from this code?**

---

**My Current Code**

Here is my code right now:

```py
from socket import gethostname

import win32com.client
import pythoncom

import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Messaging")
from System import TimeSpan
from System.Messaging import MessageQueue


# Source: [1]
# [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msmq/ms707027%28v%3dvs.85%29
MQ_DENY_NONE = 0x0
MQ_PEEK_ACCESS = 0x1
MQ_SEND_ACCESS = 0x2


# Set up queue
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
qinfo = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo")
qinfo.FormatName = f"direct=os:{gethostname()}\\PRIVATE$\\MyQueue"
queue = qinfo.Open(MQ_PEEK_ACCESS, MQ_DENY_NONE)

# Receive a value
timeout_sec = 1.0
timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout_sec)
label, body = "", ""
# TODO: timeout value does not appear working. It never waits when
#  there's no message
if queue.Peek(pythoncom.Empty, pythoncom.Empty, timespan):
    msg = queue.Receive() . # Blocking receive --> remove msg from the queue
    if msg is not None:
        label = msg.Label
        body = msg.Body
```

I run: `inspect.getfullargspec(queue.Peek)` and get:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'WantDestinationQueue', 'WantBody', 'ReceiveTimeout', 'WantConnectorType'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(<PyOleMissing object at 0x00000147F5D43BD0>, <PyOleMissing object at 0x00000147F5D43BD0>, <PyOleMissing object at 0x00000147F5D43BD0>, <PyOleMissing object at 0x00000147F5D43BD0>), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

---

**Things I've Tried**

[This question](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21207798/Python-and-MSMQ.html): saying `ReceiveTimeout=timespan` doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Replacing `pythoncom.Empty` with `pythoncom.Missing` doesn't seem to work

[This unanswered question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f519685-7121-49df-97ab-b978da9484b1/queuereceive-block-and-timeout?forum=msmq) seems very similar to mine

Comment: pythoncom has `CoWaitForMultipleHandles(Flags, Timeout , Handles )` does it helps you ?

Comment: Hi @LinPy do you mind elaborating?  It may help, it sort of seems like a workaround though.  I am wondering how to get args right for timeout on `queue.Peek`

Comment: Just a thought, but other examples I've seen of of this interface in Python simply use an integer (in milliseconds) for their timeout.  Maybe pywin32 isn't handling TimeSpans the way you expect...

Comment: @PeterBrittain thank you, that actually did the trick!  I posted your comment as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original question's comments, @PeterBrittain suggested to try just using:

> an integer (in milliseconds) for their timeout

I got around to trying that out, and actually, it worked!  I found `float` values to work as well.  Here is some sample Python code:

```py
timeout_sec = 1.0
queue.Peek(pythoncom.Empty, pythoncom.Empty, timeout_sec * 1000):
```

Thank you @PeterBrittain!

Answer (score 0):

I found this article  [sending-msmq-messages-python](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/sending-msmq-messages-python.html)

The article shows you how to send and receive a message using msmq. I don't understand why you can't just standard socket connection syntax to say if I haven't received a packet/connection then close connection

```
import select
mysocket.setblocking(0)
ready = select.select([mysocket], [], [], timeout_in_seconds)
if ready[0]:
    data = mysocket.recv(4096)
```

So something like that shouldn't be too difficult. Worst case scenario create a thread that checks every timeout_time if a variable is zero or not. If it's zero close queue nothing received if it's >0 set to zero and wait for more messages.
I also found a GitHub about asynchronous msmq for python logging.
 [asynchronous msmq](https://github.com/gouthambs/karuth-source/blob/master/content/articles/asynchronous-msmq-log-handler-python.rst) 
This one just said receive while True
 [dlopes7 msmq](https://github.com/dlopes7/python-msmq-sample/blob/master/consumer.py)

```
import time
t_end = time.time() + 60 * 15
messages=0
while time.time() < t_end or messages>0:
    msg = queue.Receive()
    messages+=1
    if(time.time() > t_end and messages>0):
        messages=0
        t_end = time.time() + 60 * 15
    print(f'Got Message from {queue_name}: {msg.Label} - {msg.Body}')
```

Not the answer you wanted but one that will work.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHearn!  Thank you for providing multiple useful workarounds.  As such, I am awarding you the bounty :)

Comment: Thank you! @IntrastellarExplorer